# Get values in another column depending on values in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataFrame with columns **A, B, & C**. I want to select values in **B** that sum up to value in column **A** then select values in column **C** whose index match the selected values from column **B**.

```
A         B                                C
3       [1, 2, 5]                [107385, 128281, 133015]
4       [9, 2,5,2]               [108664, 110515, 113556, 54545]
2       [1.0, 2, 4, 8, 4]        [134798, 133499, 125396, 114298, 133915]
```

Say for the last row, i will just pick **2** from column **B** coz it exactly equal to **2** in Column **A**, and then i will select **133499** in column **C** and return that number only from **C**.

```
Output
      **D**
[107385, 128281]
[ 110515,  54545]
[ 133499]
```

Can someone help me here? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit confuse about what you want. Could you explain more your algorithm?

Comment: Values in Column A should sum up to values in Column B. then select those values that sum up to A. then select the values i Column C that matches the index of values in column B that sum up to the value in column A. Hope that helps

Comment: explain why you select [107385, 128281] in the first row please

Comment: because  values in column B (1, 2) adds up to the value 3 in column A and at the same time indexes for 1 and 2 match the index for  [107385, 128281] in column C

Comment: What happens if there are multiple possible selections from column B? i.e A is 6 and B is [3, 4, 3, 2]?

Comment: Then just one of them is selected, mainly the first one can be selected just to end the loop earlier then move to the next row in case you have many rows